ion-searchbar with FormGroup to only search when the value inserted is minLength (3)
I'm trying to make a  that don't search until the inserted value is higher or equal than 3
but the method i try didn't work
:(
Home.page.html
<form [formGroup]="search">
    <ion-searchbar formControlName="ionSearch" [debounce]="500"
    (ionInput)="handleInput($event)" placeholder="Search product"></ion-searchbar>
  </form>

Home.page.ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.makeForm();
  }

makeForm() {
    this.search = new FormGroup({
      ionSearch: new FormControl("", Validators.minLength(3))
    });
  }


Do you mean like this? I just check if the length is greater than or equal to three and execute the filtering!
  handleInput(event) {
    const query = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    if (query.length >= 3) {
      this.results = this.data.filter(
        (d) => d.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1
      );
    } else {
      this.results = this.data;
    }
  }

Stackblitz Demo
